# Solaris awk - $0 behaving differently depending on context

Tags: awk, solaris, sunos

**Note**: this issue only applies to Solaris's default awk.
GNU awk/gawk and Solaris's XPG4 awk do not exemplify this behavior.
Furthermore, this is more of a "*why*" question, not a "*how do I fix this*" question.

---

Using the following example input:

```
a 10
b 20
c 42
d 99
f 01
```

In my awk script, I'm extracting the last field `$NF` to use as a value and using everything else as a key.  To do this, I set `$NF = ""` and use what remains in `$0` as the key.
However, I get different results depending on if I use `$0` directly or if I assign it to a variable first:

```
awk '{
    # Extracting and removing the value
    value = $NF;
    $NF = "";

    # Copying $0 to a variable
    key = $0;

    # Displaying the difference between "key" and "$0"
    printf("key = <%s>\n", key);
    printf("$0  = <%s>\n", $0 );
    printf("\n");
}' < input.txt
```

This results in the following output:

```
key = <a 10>
$0  = <a >

key = <b 20>
$0  = <b >

key = <c 42>
$0  = <c >

key = <d 99>
$0  = <d >

key = <f 01>
$0  = <f >
```

Note that `$0` is missing `$NF`, but `key` somehow still contains it even though it should be a direct copy of `$0`.

**Why does this happen?**
Is there something in the formal awk language definition that defines this behavior?

Comment: It looks like that version doesn't rebuild `$0` when you change the last field. `$1 = $1` would probably trigger it; see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html

Comment: This being said, according to the awk as specified by POSIX (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html), setting any field should cause re-evaluation of `$0`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - I think you're on to something.  If I change the order to `print $0`, `key = $0`, `print key`, then the output is identical.  I'm not sure why `print $0` forces an update but `key = $0` doesn't, but at least we're getting somewhere.

Comment: realize that Sun `awk` is the original awk version created by Aho, Wein.., Kern.. Any Sun user knew to use `nawk` to get the features as documented in 'The AWK Programming Language' (Wiley pub). There are occasional discussions in that book about the original awk vs the "New"  awk  (1988~) ;-) . But you're trying to count the number of angels dancing on the head of a pin Move on, time flies ;-) Good luck

Comment: @shellter -berger -ighan

Comment: @tripleee ; Yep thanks. I wasn't sure if my answer would exceed the limit, so I cheated to save some space AND I'm never quite sure (with out digging out the book), if it's Weinberg or Weinberger, or Wien.. .

Comment: With respect to *why*, what's likely very close to the original Solaris `awk` source code can be found at http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/cmd/awk/

Comment: instead of another $1 = $1, try changing :::::::::: value = $NF ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: to value = $(NF+=0)